# Boot process check for a suspicious terminal window on start up - macOS Monterey

Tags: macos, startup

macOS Monterey version 12.3.1 (21E258) shows a suspicious terminal window on start up. The title of the window is "Window".

- See at second 3 here https://youtu.be/ajRt_2cU6OQ?t=3
- Still cropped from video…
  [image: cropped from video]

## Check test

- To respond @Saaru Lindestøkke No Login Items at System Preferences > Users & Groups
- Below the output of [Ander Ustarroz](https://www.linkedin.com/in/anderustarroz/?locale=en_US) [instrunctions](https://www.developerfiles.com/location-of-startup-items-and-applications-on-mac-os-x/)

### Location of startup items and applications on MAC (OS X)

Quick cheatsheet to know where to look when you need to rid off some startup item, app or service.

#### Applications that run on Startup

`ls -lah /Library/StartupItems`

- Output [bin](https://pastebin.com/HJ2vBueT)

#### Property list (plist) items running on startup

`ls -lah /Library/LaunchDaemons`

- Output [bin](https://pastebin.com/nD6MKZfn)

`ls -lah /System/Library/LaunchDaemons`

- Output [bin](https://pastebin.com/6HgspV4M)

#### Applications that launch on User Login

You should be able to add/remove most applications from your user account. Go to **System preferences** -> **Users and groups** -> **Select user** -> **Login Items**.
[image: no login items]

By console you can check in the following folders:

`ls -lah ~/Library/LaunchAgents`

- Output [bin](https://pastebin.com/XGTiBTPL)

`ls -lah /Library/LaunchAgents/`

- Output [bin](https://pastebin.com/3PEdCVRb)

`ls -lah /System/Library/LaunchAgents/`

- Output [bin](https://pastebin.com/GDxvZNDH)

#### Applications that run on a set schedule

Check your crontab with `crontab -l`

- Output [bin](https://pastebin.com/PwXVKLcS)

#### Check Kernel Extensions

In the command line: `kextstat`

- Output [bin](https://pastebin.com/20WQC0MD)

#### Check Login and Logout Hooks

for Login: `defaults read com.apple.loginwindow LoginHook`

- Output [bin](https://pastebin.com/KqVerpWM)

for Logout: `defaults read com.apple.loginwindow LogoutHook`

- Output [bin](https://pastebin.com/8wdYyjp2)

Comment: I would first check if your machine is set to start a program/script on login. Can you check the [startup items](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/open-items-automatically-when-you-log-in-mh15189/mac) to see if something is being started there? If you don't find anything there, can you please check the locations in [this article](https://www.developerfiles.com/location-of-startup-items-and-applications-on-mac-os-x/)? Please [edit] your question with your findings.

Comment: As a big hammer, let's make sure that logging in with **Safe Mode** eliminates this: Can you reboot and keep holding the **Shift** key until you're at the login screen and confirm that this no longer occurs?

Comment: @pion yes I confirm that in safe mode this no longer occurs

Comment: Hi @SaaruLindestøkke I edited the question with my findings. Still the suspicion terminal window runs on start up, in the exactly moment after login. Any follow up on this?

Comment: I looked through all the pastebins (it's a bit user unfriendly to paste that somewhere else, please just include it as code in your question) and two things caught my eye: in [`~/Library/LaunchAgents`](https://pastebin.com/XGTiBTPL) you have a file `homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`. And in [`/Library/LaunchAgents/`](https://pastebin.com/3PEdCVRb) you have `com.bit4id.bit4ctktoken.app.lanucher.plist` (note the spelling mistake in `launcher`, is this something you've added yourself?). Perhaps one of those are launching a script on login?

Comment: You can use [LaunchControl](https://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/) to inspect these .plist files with a more user friendly interface.

Comment: I `sudo find / -name '*bit4id*'` saved results into a `file` and then `xargs < ~/file -I {} sudo rm -rf {}` so then again `sudo find / -name '*bit4id*'` and now it’s clean. I am restarting and let you know the result

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke the glitch was this suck `bit4id` so now it’s clean! Solved! No more unwanted suspicions terminal window on start up! You rock my friend! Thanks !

Comment: Eh well... that's an approach. I wouldn't have deleted the file so abruptly (but maybe you've made a backup?). It could possibly be related to the correct functioning of your system, e.g. the [bit4id smartcard reader](https://www.bit4id.com/en/devices/smart-card-reader-minilector-evo/). Well, it's your machine, I'm glad I could be of help.